# i want to write a httpServer .but the socket.read() is always blocked when i received the http request

Tags: java, sockets

I want to write an `httpServer`, but the `socket.read()` is always blocked when I received the HTTP request. I found the problem is that the socket client (HTTP request) has not proactively closed. The `socket.read()` in server is always blocked. I have not found the solution.

```
Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int result;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while ((result = socket.getInputStream().read(data)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(new String(data));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing an HTTP server?

Comment: And why haven't you read RFC 2616 before starting?

Comment: @sunrise76 HTTP requests don't start with a binary length word. What are you talking about?

Comment: @chrylis i just write it for practice and to understand the how a server work.

Comment: @EJP oh i don't know this before.i will google it know.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that the socket client (HTTP request) has not proactively closed.

The problem is that you haven't read RFC 2616. HTTP requests aren't terminated by end of stream. If the client had closed the socket, how could it possibly read the response? What you're saying doesn't make sense.

> I have not found the solution.

You haven't looked. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, particularly the parts about the Content-length header.

Comment: thx, i just even don't know the key words to google before u told me about RFC 2616.

Comment: ok..RFC 2616 is a http 1.1 protocol. i heard it ,but i haven't read it .i just know little about the content from the browser.

Comment: If you plan on implementing the protocol you need to start by reading the protocol specification.